# Modal Video Problems

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Slight problem with modal videos. I have done 3 modal videos obviously each with a seperate link. But when i click on the bootstrap pill to open the area where the modals are, all 3 videos start playing in the background without even opening the modals?

I'm after the video's only playing when opened, and then stopping and resetting when the modal is closed (The first part i cant really find an answer to whereas the second part i have seen answers i could make sense of so its mainly the first part im not sure where ive gone wrong).

If anyone has time to help me out i'd appreciate it

Modal Code

```
<div class="row">

    <div id="vid1" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-video1">
            <span class="video-link-text">Example 1</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="vid2" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-video2">
            <span class="video-link-text">Example 2</span>
        </a>
    </div>

     <div id="vid3" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-video3"> 
            <span class="video-link-text">Example 3</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal Videos -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-video1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-video">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="../video/example1.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-video2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-video">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="../video/example2.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-video3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-video">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="../video/example3.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery (still a noob with it so i do apologise)

```
$('.launch-modal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $( '#' + $(this).data('modal-id') ).modal();
    });
```

Comment: Nobody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code, you put videos inside iframe tags. The side effect of this is the videos will be automatically played.

Instead of using `iframe` tag, use `video` tag and you have an option to turn off `autoplay`. For example (`autoplay` is off by default)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="../video/example2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

More information on the `video` tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: thanks, that stopped it autoplaying, much appreciated. Now to figure out how to start it and stop it only when the modal is open then closed

Comment: @MichaelBirtwistle Any problems with playing the videos after opening the modal?

Comment: @MichaelBirtwistle I ask because you did not accept my answer. What is missing from my part?